# storing a directory name with spaces in a bash variable

Tags: bash, file

*(Note:  after some more research I have a partial answer, but I don't like having to write the actual commands against that variable differently depending on embedded spaces or not.  I'll accept better suggestions)*.

I like to store various work variables in bash as I am working on something.  This avoids having to type it up every time and also helps when you come back to work on it some time later (stick the assignment in a **localprofile.sh** file and `source` that later...).

I'd like to store a directory name with spaces in it.  I know how to do deal with spaces in file/directory names interactively, using either quoting or \-based escaping:

```
$ ls -1 /Users/myuser/Library/Application\ Support/ | tail -5
iTerm2
icdd
org.videolan.vlc
pip
videosubscriptionsd
```

or

```
$ ls -1 "/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/" | tail -5
iTerm2
icdd
org.videolan.vlc
pip
videosubscriptionsd
```

Now I'd like to assign that directory to a bash **$dn** variable and that's not working so well.

Here are some various tries.  On purpose I stayed away from ~-based shell extension.

```
dn='/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/'
echo ''
echo ''
echo $dn
ls -1 $dn

dn='"/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/"'
echo ''
echo ''
echo $dn
ls -1 $dn

dn=/Users/myuser/Library/Application\ Support/
echo ''
echo ''
echo $dn
ls -1 $dn

dn="/Users/myuser/Library/Application\ Support/"
echo ''
echo ''
echo $dn
ls -1 $dn
```

each one of these shows a variation on `ls: /Users/myuser/Library/Application\: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

OK, found this by broadening by googling without specifying mac or osx - this is a generic bash issue:  [Stackoverflow how to add path with space in bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787476/how-to-add-path-with-space-in-bash-variable)

And, translating that to my question, both "interactive approaches", i.e. quoting or \-escaping work, as long as you wrap the bash variable in its own double-quotes when you run the commands:

```
dn='/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/'
ls -1 "$dn" | tail -5

dn=/Users/myuser/Library/Application\ Support/
ls -1 "$dn" | tail -5
```

**Don't use single quotes above** - there is no bash substitution happening in that case and you get `ls: $dn: No such file or directory`.

The drawback here is having to wrap the variables in double-quotes or not depending on embedded spaces.

`dn="'/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/'"` and then not having quotes doesn't work, btw.

Comment: As a general rule: **Always** wrap variable names in `""` when using them if you are not absolutely sure that their value does not contain spaces.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you assign the value in the first place, all of `foo='foo bar'`, `foo="foo bar"`, `foo=foo\ bar` assign the same value.